# Expand accordion upon first validation error of a form

Tags: validation, accordion, react-bootstrap

I have an accordion in react-bootstrap and a form with validation in it. Some form fields are on the first page of the accordion and some are on the second page. Upon validation error how can I expand the accordion page that contains the first invalid field?

I managed to get the first invalid form field, but I am unable to determine which accordion page contains this field.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the first invalid form field then you can use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find it's accordion card via the class 'collapse'.
Add 'show' to its classes so it will open then you can scroll to the invalid element via [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```js
handleSubmit = (event) => {  
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      let firstInvalidFieldInTheForm = form.querySelectorAll(':invalid')[0];
      let ancestorAccordion = firstInvalidFieldInTheForm.closest(".collapse");
      ancestorAccordion.classList.add("show")
      firstInvalidFieldInTheForm.scrollIntoView();
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }else{
      this.handleSaveButtonClick();
    }
    this.setState({validated: true});
  };
```